# Line always cuts at least 9 circles

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a plane a circle with diameter $3$ is given. Inside the circle there are finitely many circles, such that the sume of their diameters is $25$. Prove that for every line in the plane, there exists a parallel line to it that cuts at least $9$ of the cirles inside the circle with diameter $3$.

---

Here's my solution:

First obviously there are at least $9$ circles inside, as the biggest diameter can be $3$ and by Pigeonhole Principle there are at least $\left[\frac{25}{3}\right] + 1 = 9$ circles.

Now it's fairly easy to notice that if a line cuts a circle it cuts the circle's diameter perpendicular to it, as well. So now let's assume the opposite, i.e. every parallel line cuts at most $8$ circles. Then as we slide the line along the segment of length $3$ (diameter of the big circle), then the sum of all the diameters is $3\cdot 8 = 24$. Contradiction. Hence the proof.

But my concern is the infinite amount of these lines and that all they have infinitesimal "thickness", so I'm not sure how rigorous this proof is. Of course we can use calculus and split the segment of length $3$, into infinitely many subintervals of size $\frac{3}{n}$, where $n \to \infty$. Then if we assume that the statement is wrong, each subinterval contributes to the total sum of diameters by less than or equal to $8 \cdot \frac{3}{n}$. Now for the total sum of diameters $L$ we have:

$$L \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 8 \cdot \frac{3}{n} = \int_a^{a+3} 8dx = 24$$

But using calculus is beyond the scope of this question. So is there a more elementary solution to this problem?

Comment: Well, since there are finitely many circles, your integral is in fact a finite sum. To write it properly is not a straightforward task, but this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose on contrary that there's no such line that cuts through 9 circles.

For each small circle, draw the diameter that's perpendicular to this line. By the assumption, if you move the line in the direction of these diameters and still overlapping the large circle, it can at the same time intersect at most 8 diameters. You can move this line for a distance at most 3. So the accumulative sum of all diameters your line pass through is at most $3 \times 8 = 24$, which makes a contradiction.